# Java Как изменить порт Spring boot сервера в нужный момент времени?

Tags: java, spring

При старте spring boot (v2.4.10) сервера можно различными способами настроить порт этого сервера. Например через командную строку:

```
-Dserver.port=НУЖНЫЙ_ПОРТ
```

или

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ThreadSpringServer.class);
app.setDefaultProperties(Collections.singletonMap("server.port", "НУЖНЫЙ_ПОРТ"));
context = app.run();
```

Или же такой вариант:

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ThreadSpringServer.class);
app.setDefaultProperties(Collections.singletonMap("server.port", String.valueOf(НУЖНЫЙ_ПОРТ)));
context = app.run();
```

Так же я встречал вариант:

```
@Component
public class PropertiesCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableWebServerFactory> {
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.setPort(НОВЫЙ_ПОРТ);
    }
}
```

Но он тоже не подходит, потому что я не могу вызвать этот код в нужный момент времени.

Подобные варианты я тестировал, и они хорошо работают, если надо инициализировать параметры при первом старте программы.

---

При этом сколько я не искал, не смог найти способ, при котором можно выполнить изменение порта сервера после, того как сервер уже был запущен. Например, я запустил сервер с портом 3333, но потом мне нужно, чтобы он слушал не этот 3333, а 4444. Тем самым, чтобы можно было 3333 изменить на 4444 в процессе работы приложения, а не только при инициализации или старте.

---

Подскажите пожалуйста, если ли способ организовать замену порта в процессе работы приложения? Может быть уже есть готовая реализация данного функционала внутри какого-то метода, чтобы можно было вызвать этот метод в нужный момент времени. Заранее спасибо большое.

Comment: Одна из проблем, что томкату без перезапуска нельзя поменять порт. Я бы посмотрел в сторону https://www.baeldung.com/java-restart-spring-boot-app

Comment: Не очень тривиальная задача, и полагаю решения из коробки просто не будет :)

Comment: Ну даже если нет решения из коробки, было бы неплохо понять хотя бы сам механизм замены, чтобы знать в каком направлении копать.

Comment: В начале я рассматривал идею о перезапуске целиком spring server, но потом решил поискать что-то получше

Comment: Можете написать зачем вам смена порта во время исполнения? Какую проблему вы этим решаете?

Comment: В моем случае, данный порт является пользовательской настройкой. Поэтому пользователь может изменить в нужный момент времени.

Answer (score 2):

Spring и Spring Boot главным образом покрывают очень стандартные варианты использования тех или иных вещей.

Смена порта веб-сервера — это весьма нетипичный случай. И обычно реализации веб-серверов не предусматривают механизм смены порта "на лету". То есть на самом деле нужно запусть новый экземпляр сервера на новом порту, погасить старый, если это необходимо. При этом веб-сервер придется вынести из жизненного цикла Spring.

То есть план примерно такой:

- отказываетесь от web-плюшек Spring Boot
- делаете класс-обертку, который будет управлять веб-серверами и сможет быть спринговым бином.
- сами выбираете и конфигурируете сервер (тут все индивидуально), скармливаете ему обработчики, которые, могут жить в спринге (@Component)
- делаете у класса-обретки метод `changePort(int)`, который погасит веб-сервер и запустит новый.

Очень грубо и верхнеуровнево это может выглядеть так:

```
@Component
public class WebServerWrapper {

    public static int DEFAULT_PORT = 3333;

    volatile Server serverInstance; // Server это какая-то реализация веб-сервера (Undertow, Jetty, Tomcat, etc)

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        serverInstance = configureInstance(DEFAULT_PORT);
        serverInstance.start();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdown() {
        serverInstance.stop();
    }

    public changePort(int newPort) {
        Server newInstance = configureInstance(newPort);
        newInstance.start();
        
        serverInstance.stop();
        serverInstance = newInstance;
    }

    // Здесь вы полностью настраиваете новый экземпляр сервера.
    // Обычно для этого сервер предоставляет какие-то фабрики или билдеры.
    private Server configureInstance(int port) {
        Server server = new .....;

        List<Object> handlers =  findHandlers();
        
        // передаете в server обработчики запросов
        
        return server;
    }
    
    // Здесь вы находите и возвращаете обработчики запросов
    public List<Object> findHandlers() { ... }
}
```

---

Пример ручной конфигурации связки Undertow + JAXRS на одном из моих проектов:

```
@Bean(name = "apiUndertow", destroyMethod = "stop")
public UndertowJaxrsServer getUndertowJaxrsServer(
        @Autowired SomeHandler1 handler1,
        @Autowired SomeHandler2 handler2,
        @Autowired SomeHandler3 handler3,
        @Autowired SomeHandler4 handler4) {

    Application app = new Application() {
        @Override
        public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
            final Set<Class<?>> clazzes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
            return clazzes;
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
            HashSet<Object> objects = Sets.newHashSet(
                    handler1,
                    handler2,
                    handler3,
            return objects;
        }
    };

    Undertow.Builder builder = Undertow.builder()
            .addHttpListener(apiPort, apiHost)
            .setServerOption(Options.WORKER_NAME, "XNIO-API")
            .setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ALWAYS_SET_DATE, true)
            .setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ENABLE_STATISTICS, false)
            .setServerOption(UndertowOptions.RECORD_REQUEST_START_TIME, false);

    UndertowJaxrsServer resteasyToUndertowIntegration = new UndertowJaxrsServer();
    resteasyToUndertowIntegration.deploy(app);
    resteasyToUndertowIntegration.start(builder);
    return resteasyToUndertowIntegration;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду изучать данный подход.